# flutter make draggable widget also a drag target

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop, flutter-web

[image]

By default in the picture above, the green box(drag target) is empty. When the red box(A) is dragged is stays in the green box and then this red box (now inside the green, also acts as a drag target). So that now the black box(B) can be dropped into it. How do I do this in flutter With Draggable and Drag target. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code you already tried. Perhaps in a dartpad or codepen format. so that its easy to verify the current behavior.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/JohannesMilke/draggable_example/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use gesturedetector(tabdowndetails) to detect "x,y" while moving users finger across the screen. You can paint target rectangle(const dimensions) dynamically following users finger.
btw. where do you plan to drag the boxes(objects, picts)?